# Eigenvalues of $A^{2018}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{2018}$.
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 1 & 4\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

My solution:

First, by substracting first row times three from second row we get:
$$
A\approx \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4\\ 0 & -8 & -8\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}
$$

We achieved the upper triangular matrix so the characteristic polynomial is:
$$
\chi_{A^{2018}}(\lambda)=det (\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4\\ 0 & -8 & -8\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}^{2018}-\lambda I)=(1^{2018}-\lambda)((-8)^{2018}-\lambda)(4^{2018}-\lambda)
$$

Therefore the set of eigevalues is $\{1,4^{2018},8^{2018},\}$.

---

Please verify if this the correct solution, and in case it isn't, help me find the correct one.

Comment: "eigenvalues and eigenvalues"??? Did you mean "eigenvalues and eigenvectors"?

Comment: Row reduction can change the eigenvalues.

Comment: @AidenChow yes, of course

Comment: The eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^n$ will be the same.

Comment: @N.S. it doesn't change the determinant, I checked that

Comment: The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of that matrix are computable immediately by visual tricks.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman can you specify what "visual tricks" you mean?

Comment: @MartinYakuza Two matrices can have the same determinant yet have different eigenvalues so your saying that the row reduction didn't change the determinant is not relevant.  If you were to talk about the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ though note that your proposed row reduction would not have actually transformed the matrix into upper triangular... you'll have some $\lambda$'s floating about still in the lower triangle.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah, I see, you are right.

Comment: That said... as alluded to already, this is essentially just a question on finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the original matrix $A$ with one extra step at the end.  Focus on that.  Once you have the eigenvalues and some corresponding eigenvectors for $A$, note that the same eigenvectors for $A$ will also be eigenvectors for $A^n$ with their corresponding eigenvalues for $A^n$ being the same as the eigenvalues for $A$ just raised to the power of $n$.

Comment: @martinyakuza the 2 by 2 at the top left has rows adding up to 4, so $[1 1 0]$ is an eigenvector with Eugene value 4. Similarly $[1 -1 0]$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-2$. You find the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matirx is the sum of a relatively easy one (symmetric) and a nilpotent matrix, and these commute. $N$ is zero except for the pair of $4$ in positions $(1,3)$  and $(2,3).$  Call the symmetric one $S$ which can be nicely diagonalized. because they commute,
$$  (S + N)^{2018} = S^{2018} + 2018 S^{2017} N. $$
It stops there since $N^2 = 0.$

I just guessed this, all that is needed is explicit $P^{-1} S P = D.$  It is not really necessary that $P$ be orthogonal. In fact, what I do is

$$ P^T S P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 \\ 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 3 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  & 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

where $PP^T = P^TP = I$

$ P^T S P = D  $  so that $S = PDP^T.$  Thus $S^{n} = P D^n P^T$ for all $n \geq 1$

the $S+N$ is called a Jordan Chevalley decomposition, sometimes much easier than Jordan canonical form. This time, not much different

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The characteristic polynomial is $c_A(x)=(x-4)((x-1)^2-9)=(x-4)^2(x+2)$.

You can check that the Jordan normal form  is $B=\begin{pmatrix} 4&1&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $A^n$ is similar to $B^n$.

But $B^n=\begin{pmatrix}4^n&4+2\cdot4^n&0\\0&4^n&0\\0&0&(-2)^n\end{pmatrix}$.

Hence we get $\{4^n,(-2)^n\}$ as the eigenvalues.

Comment: I get that the eigenvalues are: 4, 4, -2 (before raising to 2018). Also that the matrix is defective.

Comment: Ok then I need to go back to the drawing board. @Joe

Comment: I could be wrong, but that’s what I got on paper, and “R” agrees, at least with the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks @Joe.  If you have time, let me know what you think of the new solution.

Comment: That’s exactly what I get for the characteristic polynomial.